# Python timestamp (13 digits) to string returns 2074 year and how to convert 15 digits timestamp to string

Tags: python, timestamp, instagram-api

so I'm using Instagram API and I need to get time when the picture was uploaded. Usually everything is fine and timestamp looks like this:

```
>>> import time
>>> timestamp = 1497423819748
>>> time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", time.gmtime(timestamp / 1000.0)).split(' ')
['14', 'Jun', '2017', '07:03:39', 'GMT']
```

or this:

```
>>> timestamp = 1497425126
>>> time.strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT', time.gmtime(timestamp)).split(' ')
['14', 'Jun', '2017', '07:25:26', 'GMT']
```

But some media has timestamp which looks like this:

```
>>> timestamp = 3302720163189
>>> time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", time.gmtime(timestamp / 1000.0)).split(' ')
['28', 'Aug', '2074', '22:16:03', 'GMT']
```

or even this 15 digits timestamp:

```
>>> timestamp = 186693871989665
>>> time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", time.gmtime(timestamp / 100000.0)).split(' ')
['28', 'Feb', '2029', '02:05:19', 'GMT']
```

Please can you help me correctly convert these types of timestamps to string too or there's just something wrong with those timestamps?

***Update:***

```
>>> InstagramAPI.searchLocation('High Castle')
>>> location_id = InstagramAPI.LastJson['items'][0]['location']['pk']
>>> InstagramAPI.getLocationFeed(location_id)
>>> print(InstagramAPI.LastJson['items'][9]['device_timestamp'], InstagramAPI.LastJson['items'][9]['taken_at'])
77276011342 1497443715
```

Or in case with 15 digits prints this:

186693871989665 1497381289

So it seems like sometimes there is just something wrong with 'device_timestamp' that InstagramAPI gives to me, I'm not sure but looks like it returns time when photo was taken with user's device and the time on their phones is incorrect) But 'taken_at' seems to return correct timestamp, so I'll use it for now, but thx for help. If you have different answer to this I would like to see it.

Comment: Those two latter timestamps look like errors to me, they should just be disregarded.

Comment: Are you sure those are the exact values you get from the API? Looks rather like you might have let an integer overflow happen on your end ...

Comment: I see 15-digit timestamps coming back from the api as well, rather frequently. I think it might be an SMS/GMS encoded timestamp but I'm not sure yet

Answer (score 3):

In working with the API I've seen a few different formats

- Unix timestamp, 10-digits, e.g. 1200499926
- Unix timestamp with microseconds, 15-digit, e.g. 143062470196222
- Unix timestamp with microseconds, 16-digit, e.g. 1278276905502403
- Javascript format (don't know the name), 13-digit, e.g. 1508609431327

Since I am looking at these in the browser, I need them to be parsed by `Date()` so your case may vary a bit.

Either way, the only conversion necessary is to turn each of these into a 13-digit string and I have the correct output:

```
// Multiply by 1000 to include milliseconds
// > "Wed Jan 16 2008 08:12:06 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
new Date(1200499926 * 1000).toString();

// Divide by 100 to scrap the extraneous microseconds
// > "Sat May 02 2015 20:45:01 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
new Date(143062470196222 / 100).toString();

// Divide by 1000 to scrap microseconds + region
// > "Sun Jul 04 2010 13:55:05 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
new Date(1278276905502403 / 1000).toString()
```

> NOTE
>
> I'm not 100% sure why the last digit on the 15-digit timestamp is missing but the important thing is that if you can discard the microseconds and anything beyond, the first 13 digits will give you a correct timestamp

A universal way of handling this would be to always multiply by milliseconds and discard the rest (javascript):

```
let time = Number((1278276905502403 * 1000).toString().substring(0, 13))
let Date = new Date(time).toString()
// > "Sun Jul 04 2010 13:55:05 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
```